# Migration from a localized version

Tags: bug, localization

Behold guys, a freehand circle!

[image]

Is this translation behavior intended?
Found this at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40479768/3909293)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think this is intended and not a bug. This is simply the site short description, as can also be seen in the sites list of the Stack Exchange Dropwdown in the top bar:

> [image]

Comment: *Press that green thinghy ...*

Comment: @rene that's my second action, after quick look on MSE home page. ;)

Comment: I would say it *is* a bug, just one that we're incredibly unlikely to fix because doing so *correctly* would require us to maintain translations of that text in every language you can see on our site, for every single site of our network. That's somewhat unreasonable for the tiny number of questions this affects (~30 in the past 90 days).

Comment: @animuson but what about the sites list? Isn't it taken from the same place?

Comment: Yes. Essentially each site would have to have five translations: a description in English, Japanese, Spanish, Russian, and Portuguese. To display in the migration notice and sites list correctly based on which language the site you're viewing is in. Which is a lot of effort for very little gain. Hence, it's not really worth fixing it.